# ~/.ssh/config vs etc/hosts?

Tags: linux, ssh

##### Background

I have the following "Host" entry in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host 101.281.182.816 # randomized for superuser.com posting
    HostName 101.281.182.816
    User me
```

This partially overlaps with an entry in my `/etc/hosts`:

```
101.281.182.816    myserver
```

##### Question

Will the above entry in `/etc/hosts` be redundant if I update my `~/.ssh/config` to:

```
Host 101.281.182.816 # randomized for superuser.com posting
    HostName myserver
    User me
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, actually quite the opposite.

Currently (`HostName 101.281.182.816`) when you run `ssh 101.281.182.816`, it finds the entry in your config and knows that it should connect to the IP `101.281.182.816`. There's no name resolution going on.

After the change you're proposing (`HostName myserver`) when `ssh 101.281.182.816` is executed it will find out that the name "101.281.182.816" corresponds to hostname `myserver` and that hostname has to be resolved. `/etc/hosts` has the priority when resolving names, so it will be resolved to the IP `101.281.182.816` using the entry in `/etc/hosts`. If that entry was not present there, your DNS server would be used.